# Issues with adding to a database

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

My program has a method for adding dictionaries through a text file to the database. Said text file consists of a word, what manner of word it is (i.e. noun, verb, etc.) and then the associated image's file name, all formatted in the form of:

```
word#type#filename
word2#type#filename2
```

and so on. To avoid repeats of word entries, I use a `MySqlDataReader` in conjunction with a query to run through all of the rows and then add any rows that are not yet added. The code looks like this:

```
Private Sub btnCreateBank_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreateBank.Click
    Dim newOpenDialog As New OpenFileDialog
    Dim newFileStream As FileStream = Nothing
    newOpenDialog.InitialDirectory = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
    newOpenDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    newOpenDialog.FilterIndex = 1
    newOpenDialog.ShowDialog()
    Try
        newFileStream = newOpenDialog.OpenFile()
        If (newFileStream IsNot Nothing) Then
            Dim sr As New StreamReader(newFileStream)
            Dim fileContents As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
            Dim fileContentsArray() As String = Split(fileContents, vbNewLine)
            Dim fullSplitArray As New List(Of String)
            For i As Integer = 0 To fileContentsArray.Length - 1
                fullSplitArray.AddRange(Split(fileContentsArray(i).ToString, "#"))
            Next
            For j As Integer = 0 To fullSplitArray.Count - 1 Step 3
                Dim connString As String = "server=localhost;user=root;database=jakub_project;port=3306;password=password;"
                Try
                    Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connString)
                        conn.Open()
                        Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(word) FROM words WHERE word=@inputWord", conn)
                        command.Prepare()
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputWord", fullSplitArray.Item(j))
                        Dim dataReader As MySqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                        While dataReader.Read()
                            If dataReader.Item(0) = 1 Then
                                MsgBox(fullSplitArray.Item(j) & " added to system.")
                            Else
                                Using conn2 As New MySqlConnection(connString)
                                    conn2.Open()
                                    Dim addCmd As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO words(word, wordType, wordFilename) VALUES(@inputWord, @inputType, @inputFilename);", conn2)
                                    addCmd.Prepare()
                                    addCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputWord", fullSplitArray.Item(j))
                                    addCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputType", fullSplitArray.Item(j + 1))
                                    addCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputFilename", fullSplitArray.Item(j + 2))
                                    addCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                                    MsgBox(fullSplitArray.Item(j) & " added to system.")
                                    conn2.Close()
                                End Using
                            End If
                        End While
                        dataReader.Close()
                        conn.Close()
                    End Using
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox("Error: " & ex.ToString())
                End Try
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

A prior variant in which I did not include the second connection had given me the right result the first time, adding in eight rows. However, all successive attempts gave out errors that stem from what is supposedly a lack of that second connection. But now, all attempts with this subroutine output a table like this.

```
+--------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+
| wordID | word                 | wordType             | wordFilename             |
+--------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+
|      1 | acorn                | noun                 | acorn.jpg                |
|      2 | beach                | noun                 | beach.jpg                |
|      3 | chicken              | noun                 | chicken.jpg              |
|      4 | dance                | verb                 | dance.jpg                |
|      5 | elbow                | noun                 | elbow.gif                |
|      6 | fight                | verb                 | fight.gif                |
|      7 | grow                 | verb                 | grow.jpg                 |
|      8 | hat                  | noun                 | hat.jpg                  |
|     11 | acorn noun acorn.jpg | beach noun beach.jpg | chicken noun chicken.jpg |
|     12 | dance verb dance.jpg | elbow noun elbow.jpg | fight verb fight.gif     |
+--------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+
```

What I want is for the data to be loaded as seen in the first set of rows, rather than what I am now receiving in the bottom two. But I am unsure where the source of the problem lay.

The error messages don't really tell me what is going on, either. The first error message to appear tells me that the data is too long for the column it is attempting to insert it into. The second error tells me that the integer `j` in my `For` loop is out of bounds, which is occurring now because of the system seeming to read the whole string rather than three substrings.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it in the question but... What exactly *is* the issue?

Comment: Exception is a class so you cannot use ex.Tostring() . You should use ex.Message . Please try to get error message and share with us to investigate issue of your code.

Comment: @EldarZeynalov, you are incorrect. The `ToString` is absolutely appropriate!  Every class can call `ToString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you properly,
To me it looks like there was a possible flaw in your text file splitting sequence. Which is not noticeable in your posted code because you may have corrected the error after finding it?

As for the errors...
The first error is telling you that the data for the field in question (you did not mention which field it was) is too big to field into the allocated space. This too can be quantified as being caused by incorrect splitting
in your splitting sequence.

As for the second error it is unclear but I would assume do not get that error after you corrected the splitting issue?

Finally, it is recommended to move your Command.Prepare so it comes AFTER you have added all your command parameters.

**Conclusion After Your Extra Info**

After reading your comments below, I was still of the mind that the initial cause of the problems were in your splitting routine.

After use the watch tool to look at the splitting results, it was obvious what was happening. You can see the watch window below

[image: Watch Window Data]

Further more it seems to make more sense to have two separate routines for checking if the word exists and to add a new word if it doesn't exist.

By separating them out of your main processing block it makes it a lot easier to see what is going on...

So I have done that and tested it and it seems to work fine.
The main difference is that I skipped the step where you are reading in a data file and kind of simulated the contents of the in a string....

```
Private Sub btnCreateBank_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreateBank.Click
'
Dim counta As Integer = 0
Dim fullSplitArray As New List(Of String)
Dim fileContents As String = ""
Dim fileContentsArray() As String
Dim tmpWord As String = Nothing
Dim tmpType As String = Nothing
Dim tmpFile As String = Nothing
Dim Test As Boolean = False
'
Try
  fileContents = "1#acorn#noun#acorn.jpg" & vbNewLine & "2#beach#noun#beach.jpg" & vbNewLine & "3#chicken#noun#chicken.jpg" & vbCrLf & "4#dance#verb#dance.jpg" & vbNewLine & "5#elbow#noun#elbow.gif" & vbNewLine & "6#fight#verb#fight.gif" & vbNewLine & "7#grow#verb#grow.jpg" & vbNewLine & "8#hat#noun#hat.jpg"
  fileContentsArray = Split(fileContents, vbNewLine)
  For i As Integer = 0 To fileContentsArray.Length - 1
    fullSplitArray.AddRange(Split(fileContentsArray(i).ToString, "#"))
  Next
  For j As Integer = 0 To fullSplitArray.Count - 1 Step 4
    Test = False
    Try
      Test = IsWordAlreadyListed(fullSplitArray(j + 1), tmpWord, tmpType, tmpFile)
      If Test Then
        MsgBox(fullSplitArray.Item(j + 1) & " already listed in system (" & Trim(tmpWord) & ", " & Trim(tmpType) & ", " & Trim(tmpFile) & ")")
      Else
        Test = AddNewRow(fullSplitArray(j + 1), fullSplitArray(j + 2), fullSplitArray(j + 3))
      End If
    Catch ex As Exception
      MsgBox("Error: " & ex.ToString())
    End Try
  Next
Catch ex As Exception
  MsgBox("Error: " & ex.ToString())
End Try
Test = Nothing
'
End Sub


Function IsWordAlreadyListed(ByVal ParamWord As String, ByRef pRtnWord As String, ByRef pRtnType As String, ByRef pRtnFile As String) As Boolean
'
'-> Locals
Dim iwalConn As Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection = Nothing
Dim iwalCmd As Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand = Nothing
Dim iwalAdapter As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = Nothing
Dim iwalQuery As String = Nothing
'-> Init
IsWordAlreadyListed = False
iwalConn = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection()
iwalConn.ConnectionString = "YOUR-CONNECTION-STRING-HERE"
'-> Process Request
If Trim(paramword) <> "" Then
  iwalQuery = "SELECT * FROM words WHERE word='" & Trim(ParamWord) & "'"
  '-> Query Databanks
  iwalCmd = New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(iwalQuery, iwalConn)
  If iwalCmd.Connection.State = Data.ConnectionState.Closed Then iwalCmd.Connection.Open()
  iwalAdapter = iwalCmd.ExecuteReader(Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
  If iwalAdapter.HasRows Then
    iwalAdapter.Read()
    pRtnWord = iwalAdapter.GetValue(iwalAdapter.GetOrdinal("word"))
    pRtnType = iwalAdapter.GetValue(iwalAdapter.GetOrdinal("wordType"))
    pRtnFile = iwalAdapter.GetValue(iwalAdapter.GetOrdinal("wordFilename"))
    IsWordAlreadyListed = True
  End If
  If iwalCmd.Connection.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then iwalCmd.Connection.Close()
Else
  MsgBox("Error: Invalid or missing word parameter!")
End If
'-> tidy up
iwalCmd = Nothing
iwalAdapter = Nothing
iwalQuery = Nothing
iwalConn = Nothing
'
End Function

Function AddNewRow(ByVal ParamWord As String, ByVal ParamType As String, ParamFile As String) As Boolean
'
AddNewRow = False
Dim arnConn As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection = Nothing
Dim arnConnString As String = "YOUR CONNECTION STRING HERE"
arnConn = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(arnConnString)
arnConn.Open()
Try
  Using arnConn
    Dim addCmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO words(word, wordType, wordFilename) VALUES(@inputWord, @inputType, @inputFilename);", arnConn)
    addCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputWord", ParamWord)
    addCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputType", ParamType)
    addCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputFilename", ParamFile)
    'addCmd.Prepare()
    addCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox(ParamWord & " added to system.")
    AddNewRow = True
  End Using
Catch ex As Exception
  MsgBox("Error: " & ex.ToString())
Finally
  arnConn.Close()
End Try

End Function
```

Comment: I believe the second issue comes from how my For loop operates. When the entire file is split, every third index is where the new "row" starts. So my For loop steps up by three every time to start with a new set. But in this code, because of how it works, I think it ends up moving out of bounds. I have not changed the text-splitting code since posting, since I know for certain it works when I had tried it previously. The issue had only cropped up once I modified the code for a second connection item, which was suggested to me as a way of dealing with errors regarding the `MySqlDataReader`

Comment: I didn't see your response until I just got in, but this solution works perfectly. Thank you for the help.